# Listing file names from a folder

Tags: android-listview, file-listing

I have list of files saved in a folder and i am putting this logic to get them in a array..still it is showing just the first name can u please help me out..

```
filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/openedpages/";
    file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists()) {

        filenew = file.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < file.listFiles().length; i++) {
            arr = new ArrayList<String>();
            arr.add(filenew[i].getName());

        }
        System.out.println("print arr " + arr);

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please keep arr = new ArrayList(); out of for lop and try.

Comment: yeah thanks...it was creating an another arr coz i declared it twice.. thanks a lot...:)